# Sync data from Google spreadsheet to Cloud SQL using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating an application where I will be inserting spreadsheet data to Cloud SQL using jdbc service. I would like to know answers of following :

Q1. What will happen if the insert statement is executing and someone closes the spreadsheet/script?

Q2. is there any possibility of inserting the data to Cloud SQL using Google Apps script in offline mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both questions is actually a similar one - since both Cloud SQL and Apps Script are entirely always online cloud systems - it doesn't matter if the file is closed or if a user goes offline. The script should run to completion.